# AWS SES - first email takes too long

Tags: amazon-web-services, email, amazon-ses, amazon-simple-email-service

I have a Django application deployed in AWS Elastic beanstalk and we are using AWS SES to send emails. After a user sign up, we send a confirmation email. However, most users are experiencing a delay when receiving this email.

I've tried with multiple email addresses and the first email sent to an address always take up to 5-10 minutes to appear in the mailbox. The strange thing is that when the email appears in the mailbox, it shows the time that left AWS SES.
For example, if I sign up at 10:00:00:00. I can see that the connection to AWS SES was successfully established and that the email was sent at 10:00:00:68. Then, on AWS Cloud Watch I can see that delivery happened around that time too (let's say 10:01:23). When I check the mailbox nothing is there. I keep checking for the the next 5-10 minutes and nothing is there. Then around 10:11 the email is listed on the mailbox. Received time: 10:01. Emails are received right away after the first one.

However, if I send an email to an address for the first time from the "Send test email" console, the email is also received right away.

So I'm guessing the email is successfully deliver to an ISP but it takes a very long time to appear in the recipient’s inbox. And that happen because the email is seen as non trusty? How can a solve this?

Comment: Sounds like greylisting

Comment: @marsh-wiggle This is not happening in Hotmail tho.

Comment: You can enable logging for ses(using firehose put in s3) if contacting support is not an option and confirm the email does get delievred to the remote mail server. If it gets delivered right away, then in that case, aws cannot do anything. Your only option is to ask the remote mail server support.

Comment: No solution here, but can confirm I have the same issues. Using SES to send test messages to a gmail account, and the first takes a few minutes, while messages after this to the same account is received more or less immediately. Feels like a warm up situation on AWS side to me.

Comment: I'm experiencing the exact same issue. Has anyone here found a solution or the cause of the problem?

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue. Does anyone know the solution?